# Filtering out shadows when diffing frames in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I am using OpenCV to process some videos where a user is placing their hands on different parts of a wall. I've selected some regions of interest and I'm currently just using `cv2.absdiff` on the original image of the wall with no user and the current frame to detect whether the user has their hand in a region of interest by looking at the average pixel difference. If it's above some threshold, I consider that region "activated".

The problem I'm having is that some of the video clips contain lighting and positions that result in the user casting a shadow over certain ROIs, such that they are above the threshold. Is there a good way to filter out shadows when diffing images?

Comment: This is a common problem - I would first suggest segmenting your regions of interest by a combination of thresholding and binarisation. It might help if you can post some example images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCV has a [Mixture of Gaussian based background subtractor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=mog#backgroundsubtractormog) which also has an option to account for shadow. You can use this instead of absdiff. MOG can be a bit slow though, compared to absdiff.

Alternatively, you can convert to HSV, and check that the Hue doesn't change.

Comment: OpenCV's BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=mog#backgroundsubtractormog2) seems to be an improvement.

Comment: Interestingly, converting to HSV and using V (i.e. the third matrix in the np array) for thresholding works best. It seems the first matrix (which I assume is hue) fluctuates wildly, which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could first detect shadow regions in the original images, and exclude them from the difference imaging part. [This paper](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/~venky/SE263/papers/Salvador_CVIU2004.pdf) provides a simple but effective method to detect shadows in images. They explore a colour space that is invariant to shadows.